# Show MySql Data from Database On date Selection from Php Using Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am building an application that has the functionality like

3 tabs created using javascript:

```
Mapview
ListView
Post Events
```

In the list view i have to fetch data from the mysql table.
the functioning has to be like this that i have a textfield onclick which user can select the date and a button for execution. once the date has been selected upon button click it has to fetch data from the database. So shall i have to use ajax in doing this? The data has to be displayed in a particular division of my html and it has to stay on the page itself once the content has to retrieved. That is the user has the provision of selecting another date. My problem is i am new to AJAX and i am only on the starter stage. Can anyone help me doing this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
{
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="1">Peter Griffin</option> 
<option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
<option value="3">Glenn Quagmire</option>
<option value="4">Joseph Swanson</option>
</select>
</form>
<br />
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>
</body>
</html>
```

SECOND FILE NAME IS getuser.php

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'peter', 'abc123');
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("ajax_demo", $con);
$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '".$q."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Hometown</th>
<th>Job</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Age'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Hometown'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Job'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

this is example of listbox when u select list box related information is display using Ajax
Just u have to create database name is ajax_demo.